# MYSQL : Merge / Concat data if name exist in under the bracket or outside bracket

Tags: mysql

I am in a confusion to write a query of MYSQL.

What i am trying to achieve

```
CREATE TABLE paypal_ipn_orders
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(15), `neighbor` varchar(100), `color` varchar(30) );

INSERT INTO paypal_ipn_orders
    (`id`, `name`, `neighbor` `desc` )
VALUES
    (1, 'roy', 'niclo', black),
    (2, 'fosa','kol(niclo)', blue)
    (3, 'hojo','niclo(abc)', green)
    (4, 'sdojo','xxx(kkk)', osl)
```

see in neighbor there in niclo and kol(niclo) what i am trying to do is to concat or merge data if neighbor is equal to under the bracket or outside of the bracket but only thorugh SQL query

so it will become like `(1,  'niclo', 'hojo roy fosa',black blue green)` is  there any way to do that throguh sql query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the `LIKE` operator here:

```
SELECT
    'niclo',
    GROUP_CONCAT(name),
    GROUP_CONCAT(color)
FROM paypal_ipn_orders
WHERE
    neighbor LIKE 'niclo(%' OR
    neighbor LIKE '%(niclo)' OR
    neighbor = 'niclo'
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: no no i want to merge or concat data of particular if the name exist under the bracket or outside the bracket

Comment: i can concat through name only but i want to do it if the name exist under the bracket to

Comment: `SELECT id, medicinename, 
GROUP_CONCAT(companyname SEPARATOR '/// ') AS companyname , 
GROUP_CONCAT(companyname, description SEPARATOR '/// ') AS DESCRIPTION ,
GROUP_CONCAT(dosage SEPARATOR '///') AS dosage ,
GROUP_CONCAT(sideeffects SEPARATOR '/// ') AS sideeffects ,
GROUP_CONCAT(WARNINGS SEPARATOR '/// ') AS WARNINGS ,
GROUP_CONCAT(overdose SEPARATOR '/// ') AS overdose ,
GROUP_CONCAT(interaction SEPARATOR '/// ') AS interaction ,
GROUP_CONCAT(other SEPARATOR '/// ') AS other 
FROM medicine_raw_data 
GROUP BY LOWER(TRIM(medicinename));`

Comment: you are not getting me.. i want to concat the data of other column in one column group by name

Comment: You should _seriously_ normalize your data.

Comment: :( i can concat through simple name but not insde () :(